# IBAction called in response to code interaction with UI element

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, ibaction

In previous versions of iOS, IBActions were only triggered in response to user action. Now, it seems that they are also triggered by interactions through code *on the same thread* as the user interaction... I probably didn't word it that well, but here is an example:

```
@IBAction func switchToggled(_ sender: UISwitch) {
     sender.setOn(!sender.isOn, animated: true)
}
```

Neato. There's our element. The behavior that I would expect in iOS 9 and below is:

1. User taps switch
2. Animation begins
3. IBAction is hit, and animation reverses

However, in iOS 10, step 3 is revised to

3. IBAction is hit, `setOn` is called within action, then IBAction is hit again

For `UISwitch`, the IBAction only seems to get called twice.

My guess is that since the second `setOn` matches the direction of the current animation, it doesn't trigger another `valueChanged` event for the switch, therefore not triggering a 3rd IBAction.

Another observation is that if the `setOn` method is called in a completion block or something, it does not trigger the IBAction. For example:

```
someViewController.present(someOtherController,
                           animated: true,
                           completion: { theSwitch.setOn(true) })
```

This does not trigger an IBAction, regardless of the animation state of the `UISwitch`

Was there a change in iOS 10 that I was not privy to? Or is my assumption that IBActions are exclusively meant for explicit user interactions incorrect? (Yes, I know you can manually send events to UI elements to make them do things, but this isn't what I'm talking about)

Cheers!

Comment: I tested this and it looks like a bug to me. According to the document for both iOS9 and iOS10 `setOn` is not supposed to send action messages but in this particular situation it seems that it is sending an action message.